# Are these vectors linearly independent? How can I check?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

I want to know if these vectors are linearly independent?  The vector space is 3 dimension R, like (1,0,0) type of vectors.

The three vectors are (8,9,1), (1,4,5), (0,7,2).

How can I check if the vector are linearly independent?

I know two vectors are linearly independent if one is not scalar multiple of the other vector.

How can I check linear independence for three vectors?

Answer (score 2):

Three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are linearly independent iff the determinant of the matrix having them as columns (or rows) is non-zero. The question now may be: is there a really fast way to check that
$$ \det\begin{pmatrix}8 & 9 & 1 \\ 1 & 4 & 5 \\ 0 & 7 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\neq 0 $$
? Well, **yes**. Such determinant is for sure an integer number, and it has the same parity of the determinant of the matrix 
$$ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
given by the reduction of the previous matrix $\!\!\pmod{2}$. The last determinant is trivially odd, hence the original determinant is odd, too: in particular, non-zero. That ensures that the given vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: I have to get manicure for my hands.  I will come back in one hour

Answer (score 1):

Consider the system

$$\begin{pmatrix} 8 & 1 & 0 \\ 9 & 4 & 7 \\ 1 & 5 & 2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

How many solution does the sysem have?

If the system has exactly one solution, then it is linearly independent. Otherwise, it is not.

Comment: How can check for one solution?

Comment: Are you familiar with row operations? reduced row echelon form?

Comment: How come you say row operations but put vector as column?

Comment: Can you give me answer?

Comment: Suppose we want to know if $\left\{ v_1,v_2,v_3\right\}$ are lienarly independent. we want to figure out if $x_1v_1+x_2v_2+x_3v_3=0$ has nontrivial solution? We can rewrite this as $$\begin{pmatrix}v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}=0$$ has nontrivial solution. Hence, that is why I end up putting them as columns. We also know that row operations preserve that solution sets, hence, I propose row operations.

Comment: You can also solve the system of equations by doing substitution.

Comment: I will be back.  I'm getting manicure and bubble tea.

Answer (score 1):

Can you find the determinant of a square matrix?

The three vectors. $(8,9,1), (1,4,5), (0,7,2)$ will be linearly independent if:

$$\begin{vmatrix} 8 & 1 & 0 \\ 9 & 4 & 7 \\ 1 & 5 & 2\end{vmatrix} \neq 0$$

---

You should have access to a theorem something like:

**Theorem:** Let $A$ be a square $n{\small \times}n$ matrix.   Then the following are equivalent:

- The columns/rows of $A$ are linearly independent.
- The columns/rows of $A$ form a basis in $\Bbb R^n$ .
- The columns/rows of $A$ span $\Bbb R^n$ .
- $\det(A)\neq 0$ .
- $A$ is invertible.
- The reduced row echelon form of $A$ has a leading $1$ in each row.
- And several other conditions found in most primers on Linear Algebra.

Comment: determinant from calculus?  u sure?  i know determinant from calculus.  just takes a lot of time to compute

Comment: is there faster way to check if vector is linear independence

Comment: $8(4\cdot 2-7\cdot 5)+1(7\cdot 1-9\cdot 2)$ does not take a long time to compute.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically, it would be "Are these vectors linearly independent?".

It appears that you do not know the actual **definition** of "independent".  A set of vectors $\{v_1, v_2, \cdot\cdot\cdot, v_n\}$ is said to be "linearly independent" if and only if there exist n numbers, $a_1, a_2, \cdot\cdot\cdot, a_n$ **not all 0**, such that $a_1v_1+ a_2v_2+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ a_nv_n= 0$. (With only two vectors, $v_1$ and $v_2$, $a_1v_1+ a_2v_2= 0$, with $a_1$ not equal to 0, is equivalent to $v_1= \frac{a_2}{a_1}v_2$ and with $a_2$ not equal to 0, to $v_1= \frac{a_1}{a_2}v_1$ which is where your "one is a multiple of the other is from.)

Do there exist numbers, a, b, c, **not all 0** so that a(8,9,1)+ b(1,4,5)+ c(0,7,2)= (8a+ b, 9a+ 4b+ 7c, a+ 5b+ 2c)= (0, 0, 0).  So you need to solve the three equations: 8a+ b= 0, 9a+ 4b+ 7c= 0, a+ 5b+ 2c= 0. a= b= c= 0 is an obvious solution.  Do there exist **other** solutions?

Comment: exist? that is very abstract.  how can I show it is or is not exists the numbers?  do i write proof?

Comment: what is the answer?

Comment: I just told you how to show such numbers exist: **find** them!

Comment: how i can find? please do not yell, it is rude

Comment: why linear algebra so difficult.  dependence, independence, matrix, proofs, why so abstract, it's no use

Comment: Ironically, you gave an incorrect definition of linear **independence**, @user247327.

Comment: "Ironically, you gave an incorrect definition of linear independence, @user247327".  Yes, I foolishly gave the definition of "linear **dependence**, not "independence!

Answer (score 0):

For the definition of linear independence consider the scalars $a_1, a_2, a_3 \in R$, $R$ is the field, such: $$a_1(8,9,1)+a_2(1,4,5)+a_3(0,7,2)=0$$ If $a_1=a_2=a_3=0$, say the vectors $(8,9,1), (1,4,5), (0,7,2)$ are linearly independent, but, if the scalars $a_1, a_2, a_3$ not are all equal to zero, say they are linearly dependent. Well, now in this part is pure vector operations. We have: 
$$a_1(8,9,1)+a_2(1,4,5)+a_3(0,7,2)=0$$
$$=((a_1)8,(a_1)9,(a_1)1)+((a_2)1,(a_2)4,(a_2)5)+((a_3)0,(a_3)7,(a_3)2)=0$$
$$=((a_1)8+(a_2)1,(a_1)9+(a_2)4+(a_3)7,(a_1)1+(a_2)5+(a_3)2)=0=(0,0,0)$$
For the vector equality, we make a system of equations
$$ \left\lbrace
  \begin{array}{l}
     (a_1)8+(a_2)=0 \\
     (a_1)9+(a_2)4+(a_3)7=0 \\
     (a_1)+(a_2)5+(a_3)2=0 \\
  \end{array}
  \right.$$
If you solve the system you get $a_1=0$,$a_2=0$,$a_3=0$. As $a_1=a_2=a_3=0$ for definition, the vectors $(8,9,1), (1,4,5), (0,7,2)$ are linearly independent.

Comment: how solve the system?  how you do it?

Comment: you didn't respond me!

Comment: @Sally The answerers of this site are happy to help with a question here, but no one is here to be your personal tutor. You can't expect any one person to teach you the material from the ground up. If you are also struggling with solving a system of equations (which seems like something you should already know how to do in the middle of a linear algebra course), ask a separate question about that.